# Proper programming practice concerning databases and arraylists

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-listview, arraylist

I'm currently developing an android application and wish to save some data using sqlite. I'm very new to databases but will be reading up on them, so my question is a more theoretical one.

In my application, I have an Arraylist, where the object has fields of primitive types (String (name), String (address), etc). The user can create new objects to be added to the arraylist.

Is it good programming practice to create and populate the database from the arraylist? (Ie. make the arraylist the "middle man" between the user and database: new object -> ArrayList -> database).

For example, I want to create a listView using a custom arrayAdapter; should I pull the values directly from the database, or from the arraylist? Does it matter?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is right (because I'm not entirely sure I understand the question) but it doesn't sound like a good idea to always populate the database from an array list. If there are items that never change, why continuously update the database where it doesn't need to be? I think you should try to use one or the other.

Comment: There's cases where that makes sense and cases where it doesn't.  It depends on whether other activities/services could be changing the database and how many things are in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes to a database should happen in transactions as small as possible.  Each transaction should either happen entirely, or not happen at all.  You don't want some entity (like a person's address) to be partially stored.  If a transaction fails for some reason (like a database constraint being violated) the whole transaction should be rolled back like it never happened.

That being said, using a collection of entities to perform an insert on a database would be considered bad practice if each entity could be handled with its own transaction.  A single failure in the collection would cause the whole transaction to roll back even though some of the elements where acceptable.

If each element of the collection is inserted into the database individually, that would be fine, but then the issue is you might have to make the user deal with insertion errors long after they inserted it into the collection.  Suppose the user enters 3 addresses then hits "save" which causes them to be submitted to the database.  If address number 2 fails, you need to alert the user.  Now the user has to fix address number 2 after they thought they were done with it...

The best practice would be to populate the collection in memory with all relevant data from the database when the application loads.  When the user enters a new address, the application should first attempt to store it in the database.  If the insertion is successful, then also store it in the collection so the user can work with it.  The collection in memory should reflect the relevant data in the database as closely as possible.